# How to declare a string with double quotes in Query config object in node-postgres

Tags: node.js, node-postgres

I'm using node.js to access a PostgreSQL table using a Query config object;

The select I want to build is `'SELECT * FROM "Customers" WHERE "CustomersID" = 1'` which works fine with the DB.

Now, this is the Query object I'm using;

```
const query = {
   text: 'SELECT * FROM $1 WHERE "CustomersID" = $2',
   values : ["Customers",1],
}
```

but I get "syntax error at or near "$1" error.
I tried different ways with ' or/and " but doesn't seem to work for me.

What is the right way of declaring $1 as a string with double quotes in values array?

Thank
Gus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Parameterized Queries` / `Prepared Statements` are formatted on the server-side, which disallows variables for columns or table names, to counter SQL injection, which is sufficient though an unnecessary overkill, and thus a limitation imposed by PostgreSQL server.

Separate escaping column/table names is actually sufficient for protecting against SQL injection, but it must be done on your side, and the basic driver `node-postgres` does not support it within its query formatting.

As an alternative, [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise) fully supports this:

```
db.query('SELECT * FROM $1:name WHERE "CustomersID" = $2', ['Customers', 1]);
// OR:
db.query('SELECT * FROM $1~ WHERE "CustomersID" = $2', ['Customers', 1]);
```

It uses its own [SQL Names](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise#sql-names) notation to properly escape column/table names. We can append either `:name` or `~` to the variable to indicate that the variable represents an SQL Name, as opposed to a regular value.